# Finding certain pixel value within image

Tags: python, image, numpy, opencv, for-loop

I want to check for every pixel if it is red. Therefore I prepared a white image where I printed some red lines. The red lines are exactly of this colour: `(0, 0, 255)`.

With the following code, no red is detected in the image. What is wrong?

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread(r"....\red.png")
x,y,z = img.shape
print(x,y,z)

for i in range(x):
    for j in range(y):
        r = np.where((img[i,j,0]==0 & img[i,j,1]==0 & img[i,j,2]==255))
        redarray = np.array(r)
        red = np.size(redarray)

print("r: ", r)
print("redarray: ", redarray)
print("red: ", red)
```

Comment: in RGB format red should be (255,0,0)

Comment: Yes but in cv2 it is the other way round

Comment: `r`, `red`, and `redarray` reflect the last pixel value. Did you want to have an if-statement somewhere? Or create a growing list/array?

Comment: @MikhailGenkin according to [this](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_core/py_basic_ops/py_basic_ops.html), CV2 doesn't use RGB, it uses BGR.

Comment: @busybear I want to create a growing list/array

Comment: Honestly, fastest way to work this out is just to print out the RGB (BGR?!) triplet in your for loop. You'll get a massive number of values, most of which *should* be (255, 255, 255) (white), and some of which won't be. What happens if you do that? I found what I thought was red (taking a dropper on the image) did not quite give me the right values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need for-loops to accomplish this. One of the advantages of numpy!

`np.where` will do this with a little bit of work:

```
np.where((img == (0, 0, 255)).all(axis=2))
```

---

Following your example, you would need to create an if statement that would build a list of pixels if the pixel is red. `redarray` in your post will just reflect the current pixel each for loop iteration. You aren't building a list there. So something like this should work:

```
red_pixels = []
for i in range(x):
    for j in range(y):
        if np.array_equal(img[i, j], [0, 0, 255]):
            red_pixels.append((i, j))
```

Comment: Thank you, I still don't know why the code I posted doesn't detect red pixels but with your solution the red pixels are now found.

Comment: Is there also a solution without for-loops if I want to determine for each pixel of the image the number of red pixels in a direct line to a specific pixel coordinate e.g. (200|200) in the image?

Comment: I updated my post to show how you could do it in a for loop. Regarding your second question, you'd probably be better off posting a new question. Details such as how exactly "in a direct line" is defined would need to be spelled out. But you could look at some of the opencv functions. That would be a good starting point.